# Magento sub categories product not display in front site

Tags: magento, product

When i add new product to magento admin & select only sub category not the root category the product will not display in site.

When i go back & assign root category & sub category both it will display. I again go to admin & remove the root category so now product have only sub category as before. still it show on site.

The problem is that i am importing the products from .csv file, so it will only take sub category and the product added to admin but not show in front side.

The category structure is like:
Default category (root category)
- shoes (sub category)
- cloths (sub category)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you accept and upvote answers, you will get more answers on new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have added the category as a true sub category, and not another root category on the top level accidentally?

That would have the effect you are talking about.

To make sure you add it as a sub category you first need to click on your root category and then add child category after this is selected.

If your category is already a sub category the product really should show without having to add it to the root which is why I have asked :)

Comment: hey! I have theree roort category & each have 2-3 sub category. From import file i am passign sub category name & product added to that sub category by import functionality. But i cant see it if i manually not assign parent category to that product :-(